# I need help understanding an extended initializer lists error?

Tags: compiler-errors, initializer-list

I keep getting this error and I don't know what it is trying to tell me. I'm creating a matrix of characters and it is giving me this error.

warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

Comment: Perhaps show us the code too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old C++ compiler, where initilizing object using parenthesis is not permissible. You should use curly braces like,

```
Object obj (elem1,elem2..); //not permissible in C++ 98
Object obj {elem1,elem2..}; //you should use this
```

Comment: This is my code that it is giving me an error on:     levelone.board={          {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'}, 
{'X',' ','X',' ',' ',' ','X','K','X',' ','X','X','X',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','X'}, ...{'X','*','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','E','X'},       };

Comment: Can you submit more code, in what structure you are tying to fill value so that exact error can be find out.

Comment: So i have this struct:    11 struct game {
 12    char board[15][20];
 13    int Level;
 14    /*player name;*/
 15 };

Comment: And then this is the start to my function:    17 game createboard(){
 18         game levelone;
 19         game leveltwo;
 20         levelone.Level=1;
 21         leveltwo.Level=2;
 22         levelone.board={

Comment: And then i have a bunch of lines that are like this:  24            {'X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X'}, /*1*/
 25            {'X',' ','X',' ',' ',' ','X','K','X',' ','X','X','X',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','X'}, /*2*/

Comment: @anyajean As per your comment, your way seems correct. Still paste cod e in comment. Exact lines of code

Comment: and it ends like this:     37            {'X',' ','X',' ',' ',' ',' ','X',' ','X','X',' ',' ',' ','X',' ','D',' ',' ','X'},/*14*/
 38            {'X','*','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','X','E','X'}, /*15*/
 39         };